FindInstance taking very long
Trying to solve this equation:
FindInstance[e*(10000*a + 1000*b + 100*c + 10*d + e) == (a - b + c)^d && 0 < a <= 9 && 0 <= b <= 9 && 0 <= c <= 9 && 0 <= d <= 9 && 0 <= e <= 9 , {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers, 100]

But it takes a long time and crunches away for hours wihtout a result.
Looked around on this board and one suggestion was to use NMinimize, so I tried below, but seems like a syntax error?
NMinimize[{e*(10000*a+1000*b+100*c+10*d+e)==(a-b+c)^d,0<a<=9,0<=b<=9,0<=c<=9,0<=d<=9,0<=e<=9}, {a,b,c,d,e}]

Any help would be appreciated on this...
Thanks

it completes instantly if you remove the Integers domain (one instance, i.e. default), Numerically it becomes {{a->7.10673,b->6.72827,c->2.39484,d->2.05876,e->0.000104621}}

Thank you! But I need Integers only as these are digits!

For a relatively small problem space like this (only 90,000 groups of $a, b, c, d, e$), brute forcing can be efficient.
candidates = Tuples[{Range[9], Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1}];
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := (e*(10000 a + 1000 b + 100 c + 10 d + e) == (a - b + c)^d);
Select[candidates, f @@ # &]

This utilizes Tuples's ability to generate all possible combinations selecting one element from each of its input lists consecutively.
These combinations are stored in the candidates list, representing all possible integral combinations of {a, b, c, d, e} satisfying the given constraints. Then we define a test function f and simply Select all of the candidates where mapping f onto each candidate 5-tuple results in True.
407 solutions are found. Many of them work because $e=0$ or some other coincidences, but 2 solutions exists where all variables are non-zero:

{{1, 1, 6, 6, 4}, {3, 2, 7, 6, 8}}

Also note that several indeterminate $0^0$ expressions are encountered and likely discarded in this. I believe these were discarded from consideration, but it is worth checking for yourself what you want to do with that possibility.
Addressing a request in the comments, to explicitly limit the result to cases $e \neq 0$, the simplest way to is to change the candidates list. We started with:
candidates = Tuples[{Range[9], Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1}];

This creates all possible tuples choosing one element each from:
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} (* a : Range[9] *)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} (* b : Range[10] - 1 *)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} (* c : Range[10] - 1 *)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} (* d : Range[10] - 1 *)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} (* e : Range[10] - 1 *)

In order. To eliminate $e = 0$, remove 0 from the candidates for $e$ by replacing the last Range[10] - 1 with Range[9] instead:
candidates = Tuples[{Range[9], Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[9]}];
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := (e*(10000 a + 1000 b + 100 c + 10 d + e) == (a - b + c)^d);
Select[candidates, f @@ # &]


Oh my Gosh! Thanks SO much @eyorble!! Is there a systematic way of selecting those outputs from the given result? (non-zero ones)

Sure, just only start with non-zero candidates: candidates = Tuples[Range[9], 5] instead.

Pardon my ignorance but I am not sure where ",5" is placed in the original expression you gave...  like this:?   Tuples[{Range[9], 5, Range[10] - 1 ..... ?

It wasn't, Tuples supports multiple usages. 5 in this case means "pick 5 numbers from the given list", but since the constraint is actually 5 different lists I provided those instead in the answer above. See Tuples's documentation for more info.

Ok thanks I looked at the docs but cannot see where I can limit the result to non-zero e's . Can you modify the expression to do so?

I added how to eliminate the $e=0$ case specifically.

You are an utter and complete Lifesaver! Thanks!  I hope to use this for other applications also!

@Steve237, if you ever encounter a problem where the problem space is significantly larger and all possible candidates cannot fit into your memory, take a look into SelectTuples, which generates tuples meeting your criteria "on-the-fly" (instead of first generating all of them, and then selecting the ones you want) :)

@Domen Thanks, this is good, what's the difference between this one and the Tuples which eyorble gave?  Can you state the full expression here for above? In addition I am still trying to grapple with the idea that WHY are all these faster than the Findinstance? After all, both expressions have the same variabes and ranges?

@Steve237, the difference is just in the memory use. Using Tuples you first generate all possible combinations, and then select the ones you want. But if there are a lot of combinations, you will have troubles storing all this combinations in your computer memory (RAM). SelectTuples on the other hand generates the combinations one by one, and checks immediately whether it satisfies your condition. Therefore, it doesn't require a lot of memory.

Your parameter space contains $10^5$ possible combinations. FindInstance has the implementation of exchaustively brute-forcing all possible values, but by default, it doesn't do this if there are more than $10^4$ combinations. Therefore, just increase this limit.
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 10^5}}];

eqs = e*(10000*a + 1000*b + 100*c + 10*d + e) == (a - b + c)^d && 
  0 < a <= 9 && 0 <= b <= 9 && 0 <= c <= 9 && 0 <= d <= 9 && 
  0 <= e <= 9;
FindInstance[eqs, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers]

(* {{a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 6, d -> 6, e -> 4}} *)

See also How to solve this equation over the integers with Mathematica? and other questions on this topic.
Note that once you've increased the limit, you can also use Reduce or Solve, which will give you all 407 solutions.
Solve[eqs, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers]
(* {{a->1,b->1,c->0,d->1,e->0}, <<406>>} *)

Reduce[eqs, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers]
(* (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 0 && d == 1 && e == 0) || <<406>> *)


Oh wow! did the trick, i get it now @Domen! on the memory first then execute....so this 10^4 is a hard-limit set by Mathematica? Wow.... Also why is the second solution not found by your expression? the 32768 ?

Yet, $10^4$ is set by default (try SystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints"] to see that). If you use FindInstance[..., Integers, 2000], you will get back all 407 solutions (as calculated also by eyorble). There is also the {a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 7, d -> 6, e -> 8} among them :)

Yes thanks, I just modified e range to:  1 <= e <= 9,  but still have to put the  integers to 2+ at the minimum to get both! FindInstance[..., Integers, 2]

Not really sure what bothers you. FindInstance finds an instance (ie. one) by default. If you want more of them, you have to provide a number as the fourth argument.

Solve/Recuce/Candidates/Findinstance :  What are they each different in? If they all do the same thing? Are they used efficiently for different types of equations?

What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?

Can Findinstance or Solve  show its steps? ....

Hi @Domen:  this one does not work, no mem!  candidates =
Tuples[{Range[9], Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1,
Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1,
Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1, Range[10] - 1}];
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_, k_,
l_] := ((1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d)^3 + (1000 e + 100 f + 10 g +
h)^3 + (1000 i + 100 j + 10 k + l)^3 ==
100000000000 a + 10000000000 b + 1000000000 c + 100000000 d +
10000000 e + 1000000 f + 100000 g + 10000 h + 1000 i + 100 j +
10 k + l);

Trying this method also with 10^12 range:  SetSystemOptions[
"ReduceOptions" -> {"ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 10^12}}];
eqs = (1000 a + 100 b + 10 c + d)^3 + (1000 e + 100 f + 10 g +
h)^3 + (1000 i + 100 j + 10 k + l)^3 ==
100000000000 a + 10000000000 b + 1000000000 c + 100000000 d +
10000000 e + 1000000 f + 100000 g + 10000 h + 1000 i + 100 j +
10 k + l && 1 < a <= 9 && 0 <= b <= 9 && 0 <= c <= 9 &&
0 <= d <= 9 && 0 <= e <= 9 && 0 <= f <= 9 && 0 <= g <= 9 &&
0 <= h <= 9 && 0 <= i <= 9 && 0 <= j <= 9 && 0 <= k <= 9 &&
0 <= l <= 9;

@Steve237, where exactly are you going with all of this? :) You do realize that $10^{13}$ combinations is a lot to check via brute-forcing, right?

lol yes aware...so whats normally the upper limit which is practical?
